# Continuous movement when a key is held down

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible in jQuery to have an element continuously move when the key is held down?

I've tried a few ways but they always have a break in between animation calls. The code I currently have:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 37) {
        $('#you').stop().animate({
            left: '-=16px'
        }, 10);
    }
});
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    $('#you').stop();
});
```

Comment: Show your current code please. I suppose there is something wrong with the animation calling and not events.

Comment: Edited, but I don't think it'll help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.animate()` isn't always the best way.

```
// cache jQuery objects for performance
var you = $( "#you" )
, doc = $( document )

// variable to hold motion state
, activeMotion

// goDown motion, adjust numbers to taste
, goDown = function(){
   you.css( "left" , you.css( "left" ) - 16 );
   if ( activeMotion === goDown ) {
      setTimeout( goDown , 10 );
   }
}

doc.keydown( function( e ) {
   if ( e.which === 37 && activeMotion !== goDown ) {
      activeMotion = goDown;
      goDown();
   }
   // all directions can go here in seperate if/else statements
   // be sure to include "activeMotion !== goDown" else every time
   // keydown event fires, it will start a new goDown loop.
} );

doc.keyup( function () {
   // simply ends any motion that checked activeMotion
   activeMotion = null;
} );
```

Comment: This won't work: `you.css( "left" , "-=16px");`, `.css()` doesn't take `-=` or `+=` values, at least yet...`.animate()` does though.

Comment: @nick fixed. animate starts it's own timeout loop, in short more functions are called and redundant processes created. animate is nice to go from point a to b in a smooth animation, for conditional incremental steps it's better to implement it like this.

Comment: A nicer way to do this is with the function callback option of `offset`: `you.offset(function(idx, oldOffset) { return {top: oldOffset.top, left: oldOffset.left - 16};});`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animating the element, rather just move it by some amount of pixels. 16 will probably be too much because it will go too fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seeing the break between animation calls because of your timing.

If you look at your operating systems keyboard repeat time interval, it should be around 35 milliseconds - [test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Gdvnw/).

On top of that you are animating every 10ms, not counting the time it takes to run all the animation functions, etc. So why not simplify the animation and not worry about time intervals ([try this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/A35qW/)):

```
var block = $('.block'),
    leftPos;
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    leftPos = block.position().left;
    leftPos += (e.which == 37) ? -5 : 0;
    leftPos += (e.which == 39) ? 5 : 0;
    block.css('left', leftPos);
});
```